# Plots different sizes of radius in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot multiple circles with different sizes, but when I plot is not appearing all, just the biggest. Im trying:

```
set key title "START" on inside left top  
set xlabel "semi eixo maior AU"  
set key title font "arial,12"  
set ylabel "excentricity"  
set xrange [0:3]  
set yrange [0:1]  
set xtics 0.5  
set ytics 0.1  
set xtics font "arial,12"  
set ytics font "arial,12"  

plot "1.dat" using 2:3:8 with circles
```

and the file is:

```
KEPLER-B  0.22431 0.160000  90.3400 263.4640 360.0000 192.0973  2.025500E-01
Pl74      0.28422 0.004878  90.1918 360.0000 360.0000 226.5749  2.800000E-08
Pl104     0.28435 0.002581  90.4050 360.0000 360.0000 288.3514  2.800000E-08
Pl11      0.28813 0.006529  90.0343 360.0000 360.0000 204.6102  2.800000E-08
Pl57      0.29034 0.001587  90.0482 360.0000 360.0000 109.1928  2.800000E-08
Pl116     0.29716 0.007504  90.4320   0.0000 360.0000 178.7651  2.800000E-08
Pl125     0.29967 0.008853  90.3236 360.0000 360.0000 213.9914  2.800000E-08
Pl109     0.30575 0.003653  90.1797   0.0000 360.0000 184.3717  2.800000E-08
Pl64      0.32067 0.004840  90.4811   0.0000 360.0000 325.5598  2.800000E-08
Pl47      0.32184 0.007687  90.2462 360.0000 360.0000 286.0191  2.800000E-08
Pl89      0.32612 0.003941  90.0438   0.0000 360.0000  30.7960  2.800000E-08
Pl79      0.32655 0.007018  90.1604   0.0000 360.0000   1.3741  2.800000E-08
Pl60      0.33672 0.003652  90.1847   0.0000 360.0000 188.7729  2.800000E-08
Pl15      0.35077 0.007805  90.2328 360.0000 360.0000  39.8828  2.800000E-08
Pl44      0.36955 0.005037  90.3457   0.0000   0.0000  95.0128  2.800000E-08
Pl26      0.37297 0.005002  90.2850 360.0000 360.0000 253.0516  2.800000E-08
Pl53      0.37442 0.001403  90.0028   0.0000 360.0000  93.0525  2.800000E-08
Pl70      0.38793 0.008764  90.4431 360.0000 360.0000  57.3158  2.800000E-08
Pl55      0.41085 0.008903  90.1634 360.0000 360.0000 246.5066  2.800000E-08
Pl41      0.41262 0.009055  90.1495 360.0000 360.0000 230.6857  2.800000E-08
Pl114     0.42165 0.009249  90.2054   0.0000 360.0000 317.4350  2.800000E-08
Pl40      0.42239 0.001263  90.2649 360.0000 360.0000 282.1141  2.800000E-08
Pl94      0.42330 0.008025  90.1629 360.0000 360.0000 248.3528  2.800000E-08
Pl36      0.44612 0.002982  90.1900   0.0000 360.0000 124.3498  2.800000E-08
Pl117     0.44656 0.001305  90.2852   0.0000 360.0000  86.5542  2.800000E-08
Pl139     0.44675 0.007149  90.2751 360.0000 360.0000 356.4484  2.800000E-08
Pl18      0.44752 0.008138  90.4348   0.0000 360.0000  81.6764  2.800000E-08
Pl99      0.45304 0.001713  90.1202 360.0000 360.0000 252.5888  2.800000E-08
```

Comment: All but the first have a radius of 2.800000E-08 which is too small to be visible

Comment: try to plot in a different scale: `plot "test.dat" using 2:3:(10**($8)) with circles` or filter out the first point via the `with` keyword: `plot "test.dat" every ::1 using 2:3:(1e6*$8) with circles`

Comment: It dosent work, maybe i will need to do a condition to plot diferents sizes. Do you know how to do that? ty anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of line width. I changed only the last part of your code

```
plot "1.dat" using 2:3:8 with circles
```

with

```
plot "1.dat" using 2:3:8 with circles lw 3
```

The effect is shown in the image below. Anyway you'll not get a satisfying result because of the huge difference between the first radius and all the others.

[The plot with a higher line width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFJH7.png)

Maybe a solution would be making a "multiplot": you plot the first radius with the smaller ones then you make a plot inside your new plot with a zoom of the region where all the other planets are...
You can find a guide on multiplot [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/zooming-in-with-multiplot/)!

Comment: Yess! Have a big difference. Ty, i will try use a multiplot.